# Можно ли сказать "обитатели социума"?

Tags: лексика

"обитатели социума"можно ли так говорить;?

Comment: Если можете править и видите, что буковки столпились, нажмите кнопку «Править» и поправьте, что б стало правильно-преправильно!

Answer (score 5):

Нет, нельзя говорить *обитатели социума*. **Правильно** — *члены социума*.
Социум не территория, на которой можно обитать, а человеческое сообщество.

Социум — коллектив, множество людей, характеризующийся общностью социальной, экономической и культурной жизни.